# 301 redirect on query string?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

i need to do some simple 301 redirects as i am creating a site fresh and using the current domain.

How ever the website URl's all start with '?'.

For example:

```
Redirect 301 /?q=news http://websitedomain/news/
```

This results in the home page being loaded with the url still the same.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: You should start reading some documentation. The query part is _not_ part of the URL, thus you cannot directly evaluate it in redirect or rewrite rules. The documentation explains how to do that.

Comment: Which documentation is this? i will read it

Comment: Well, the documentation of the software you are using. The `Redircet` rule is implemented by Apaches "Alias" module, the `RewriteRule` and companions are implemented by apaches "Rewrite" module. Both documentations are the first hit in google when searching for them:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html & http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html In both documents you see a short index on the right hand side to jump directly to the rule you want to read about. But also the introductions are worth reading!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mod_rewrite to match against the query string :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^&]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/%1? [NC,L,R]
```